# why do you have to write interface and implementation in objective C instead just implementation

Tags: objective-c, oop

I would like to know, why is so important to write interface and implementation for every calss in Objective C. In other langauge this technique is only optional.

Comment: What about C++, Modula, et al?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, writing an interface is also optional (so is declaring methods), although the compiler will likely warn you. Writing the interface permits somebody else to reuse the binary form of your code without having to recompile it; this way you can also hide the implementation details/the code from the one who reuses your class. Also, if only you use your own class, the compiler may need some information at compile time (although Objective-C is a dynamic language) about the classes you write -- in this case you can't include the whole implementation file as it would result in duplicating your entire class, redulting in a linker error. Same reason why there are header files for any C library out there.

Answer (score 1):

Interface describes how other classes and their instances will interact with your class and its instances. You *could* just create implementation, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of OOP.